# ReactJS - is it better to provide parameter from child component, or do it in the parent one - when callback is same one?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, the parent is like this:

```
...
render() {
  <SomeChild onSomeAction={this.onSomeAction} />
  <OtherChild onSomeAction={this.onSomeAction} />
}
...
```

And I need to pass one and the same parameter with different values from each of the child components.

So - which one is better?

**1. Provide different values from each of the child components:**

`SomeChild`:

```
...
    <button onClick={(e) => this.props.onSomeAction(e, true)}>Button</button>
...
```

`OtherChild`:

```
...
    <button onClick={(e) => this.props.onSomeAction(e, false)}>Button</button>
...
```

**2. Specify the specific value in the parent:**

`Parent`:

```
...
render() {
  <SomeChild onSomeAction={(e) => this.onSomeAction(e, true)} />
  <OtherChild onSomeAction={(e) => this.onSomeAction(e, false)} />
}
...
```

`SomeChild`:

```
...
    <button onClick={this.props.onSomeAction}>Button</button>
...
```

`OtherChild`:

```
...
    <button onClick={this.props.onSomeAction}>Button</button>
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would put this information as high as possible, in this case, in the parent. If your child component does not need to know the boolean value (or any objects) passed to them and if it is not supposed to change their behavior or affect them in any way other than this function, they should not not be aware of this variable.

I would take it a step further and use curried functions to improve readability :

```
onSomeAction = value => ev => {/*   */}

render() {
  <SomeChild onSomeAction={this.onSomeAction(true)} />
  <OtherChild onSomeAction={this.onSomeAction(false)} />
}
```

A component should in general only contain information modifying their behavior to be as reusable and flexible as possible.

Using this solution you could later on send whatever you want from the function :

```
<SomeChild onSomeAction={this.onSomeAction('hi')} />
```

Or nothing :

```
onSomeAction = ev => {/*   */}

<SomeChild onSomeAction={this.onSomeAction} />
```

And what you want to receive will only be seen by the parent anyway, and does not need to appear in the child.

Answer (score 1):

Both solutions are valid. None is better than the other.
The only difference is related to `onSomeAction`.

If parent has the logic of that action then it's better to send to the child as a property.
Put the action inside the child only if the action is not the same.
Prefer to reuse code.

As far I understand from what you describe, action is shared between all children, so I'd say to define that inside the parent and pass to children as a property.